# Finding Target when initializing gestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to initialize a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` as a property of the class `ViewController` but I'm not sure what to put as the target of the gesture recognizer.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Not sure where this declaration should happen
    var menuGesture: MenuGestureRecognizer = MenuGestureRecognizer(target: self(), action: Selector("menuGestureHandler:"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuGesture)
    }
}
```

XCode suggests `self()`, but then I get the error:

```
Swift Compiler Error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call`
```

It seems to me that it is failing because I'm trying to declare the variable in the class scope. If that's the case, where/how should I declare the gesture recognizer?

I'm pretty well-versed in Objective-C but recently switched to Swift, am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let menuGesture = MenuGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "menuGestureHandler:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuGesture)
    }
}
```

---

If you want the `menuGesture` to be a property of `ViewController`, make it an optional and assign it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var menuGesture: MenuGestureRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menuGesture = MenuGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "menuGestureHandler:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuGesture!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `menuGesture` not a property of the class `ViewController` then?

Comment: Yes, it isn't a property.  Why does it need to be?  If you really need it to be a property, make it an optional and assign it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I guess you are right, it doesn't necessarily need to be a property. Thanks for the bit about the optional though! I'm still learning :)